# My TextField in Swift UI is Unresponsive to taps and clicks, text cannot be input, is there an issue with the code?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swiftui, textfield, vstack

Hi I'm an intermediate level engineer with swift and swift UI.

Currently, I am having problems with the TextField(), it is unresponsive to taps and clicks, and hence the keyboard does not show up,

However, it does show up when it is one of two main elements within a VStack, but anymore than that and it does not work,

Is there an issue with the code? and can anyone find a fix or a work around for this?

Thanks, Miles

```
{

    @State var textField = ""

    var body: some View {

        returnJoinModalContent()

    }

    func returnJoinModalContent() -> some View{

        let accentColor = Color.blue

        return VStack(alignment: .center){
            HStack{
                Text("Join Game")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                Button(action:{
                    //self.hideModal()
                }){
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50,height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(accentColor)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom,170)

            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                TextField("Enter Game Code",text: self.$textField)
                    .font(.largeTitle)

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 6)
                    .foregroundColor(accentColor)
            }
            .padding()
            HStack{
                Button(action:{
                    //self.joinGame()
                }){
                    ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 90)
                    .frame(width: 200,height: 70)
                    .foregroundColor(accentColor)
                Text("Ready!")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical,20)
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:60,height:60)
                    .foregroundColor(accentColor)

                Text("Ask your host for the game code, it can be found at the bottom of the player lobby")
                .padding()
                Spacer()

            }
            .padding(.top,60)
            .padding(.horizontal,20)

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }




}
```

Comment: FIX?: increasing the frame of the textfield slightly makes fixes the issue for now, however   i'd still like to know if there was a concrete reason for the error above

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be one of those things in swiftUI that is difficult to track down. I found the problem is your ready button. More specifically the label being a ZStack with a colored rounded rectangle as the background. If you replace your button's label with the following your text field should be selectable.

```
Text("Ready!")
.bold()
.font(.title)
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
.frame(width: 200,height: 70)
.background(accentColor)
.mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 90))
```

Comment: Problem Solved!! Do you know why that prevented the textfield from being recognised properly?

Comment: No, I don't. It seems to just be a weird bug.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that `overlay` on the `TextField` or the container of `TextField` might cause it to be unresponsive

you should remove it and replace it with `ZStack`

Comment: 2 years later, this helped me with a newly introduced bug in Xcode 15: my text fields were no longer tappable during UI tests (they worked just fine before). Adding `.allowsHitTesting(false)` to my `overlay` view fixed the tests! Thank you 